# Separate forms for all model instances

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

**I wanna get next data from POST:**

`[{'id': 1, 'number_of_product': 3, 'is_checked': on}, {'id': 2, 'number_of_product': 1, 'is_checked': off}]`,

**Now I have this:**

`'dishes': ['2', '2', '3', '4', '3', '2'], 'number_of_dish': ['2', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 'checkbox': ['on', 'on']`

```py
class Dish(models.Model):
    """Dish model"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Order creating form"""
    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    dishes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Dish.objects.all())
    number_of_dish = forms.IntegerField(
        initial=1, min_value=1, label="Number: "
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('date', 'dishes', 'number_of_dish')
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                })
        }

class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """Home view with order creating form"""
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
    form_class = OrderForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:home')


    def post(self, request):
        # TODO: [{'id': 1, 'number_of_product': 3, 'is_checked': on}, {'id': 2, 'number_of_product': 1, 'is_checked': off}]
        print(request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

And my template page:

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for dish in form.dishes %} 

            {{ dish }}
            {{ form.number_of_dish | as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.checkbox }}

        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should make use of a formset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). Right now it is impossible tor reconstruct what value belonged to what form. For example the `'checkbox': ['on', 'on']` part could belong to *any* item.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thx!

Comment: "Right now it is impossible tor reconstruct what value belonged to what form": Ya, That's why I share this question))

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, form-0-is_checked -> is this name is good from formset?

Comment: but normally a formset will add different prefixes to the different forms, so you will have a checkbox like `id0-checkbox`, `id1-checkbox`, etc. The `FormSet` can then easily move the response part to the corresponding form.

Comment: Yap! I used modelformset_factory(Dish, form=, firlds=()), And all is right)) Thx!